# Why can I not print with Kyocera ECOSYS P3055dn (network printer)?

Tags: networking, drivers, printing

After some extensive debugging (more below) and not finding any reason why the recognized network printer doesn't work (returns ""Print job was not accepted." when trying to print) I decided to see if the specific printer drivers are able to solve the issue. So I downloadede: Linux Universal Driver (Phase9_20220203) (which doesn't sound very specific) on the official kyocera webpage [https://www.kyoceradocumentsolutions.eu/en/support/downloads.name-L2V1L2VuL3ByaW50ZXJzL0VDT1NZU1AzMDUwRE4=.html`](https://www.kyoceradocumentsolutions.eu/en/support/downloads.name-L2V1L2VuL3ByaW50ZXJzL0VDT1NZU1AzMDUwRE4=.html%60) which is basically just a bunch of .deb files.

Since I do live in the EU I navigated (after reading the readme) to Ubuntu/EU/ and since I have a `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4300U CPU @ 1.90GHz` I navigated to kyodialog_i386 in which I found the specific .deb file.

On `sudo dpkg -i kyodialog_9.1-0_i386.deb` I received:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kyodialog:i386:
 kyodialog:i386 depends on libcupsimage2.
 kyodialog:i386 depends on cups-filters-core-drivers.
 kyodialog:i386 depends on python3.
 kyodialog:i386 depends on python3-reportlab.
 kyodialog:i386 depends on libqt5gui5.

dpkg: error processing package kyodialog:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.20-2ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 kyodialog:i386
```

**EDIT: Installed kyodialog_9.1-0_amd64.deb**

Thanks to a comment by @ChanganAuto I have now successfully installed kyodialog. Sadly the printer still doesn't print and the message is the same.

**EDIT: Kyocera Print Panel**

I noticed that the application Kyocera Print Panel is now available. No printers are shown in it though.

**EDIT: Copied driver**

I have now copied the responding `.ppd` to `/usr/share/cups/model/`. In this folder was already a link to all the `.ppd` files created by Kyocera. This hasn't solved my issue.

**Testing information**

I can connect to the printer using its ip. The printer is recognized in printers. The printer is shown in open printing cups. I tried the steps mentioned here without further information (as far as I can say): https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems.

I tried to pause and restart the printer.

The status of the printer is described as: `Idle - "Processing."

I do know that the printer does work in general. I am able to print successfully using a windows computer.

**Driverless**

```
driverless
ipps://EPSON%20ET-7750%20Series._ipps._tcp.local/
ipps://Kyocera%20ECOSYS%20P3055dn._ipps._tcp.local/
```

** Cups access_log **

```
sudo tail /var/log/cups/access_log
localhost - - [07/Aug/2022:11:01:37 +0200] "POST /jobs HTTP/1.1" 200 139 Cancel-Job successful-ok
localhost - - [07/Aug/2022:11:01:48 +0200] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 175 CUPS-Delete-Printer successful-ok
localhost - cups-pk-helper [07/Aug/2022:11:01:48 +0200] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 175 CUPS-Delete-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [07/Aug/2022:11:03:21 +0200] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 153 Cancel-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - - [07/Aug/2022:11:03:31 +0200] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 153 Cancel-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - - [07/Aug/2022:11:15:29 +0200] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 266 CUPS-Create-Local-Printer client-error-not-possible
localhost - - [07/Aug/2022:11:15:29 +0200] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 266 CUPS-Create-Local-Printer client-error-not-possible
localhost - - [07/Aug/2022:11:23:05 +0200] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 274 Create-Printer-Subscriptions successful-ok
localhost - - [07/Aug/2022:11:23:07 +0200] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 153 Cancel-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - - [07/Aug/2022:11:26:12 +0200] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 274 Create-Printer-Subscriptions successful-ok
```

Now I don't know what I have left to intelligently test or do.

Comment: i386=32bit OS; amd64=64bit OS. That's the mistake.

Comment: I installed kyodialog_9.1-0_amd64.deb now, but it didn't solve my problems.

Comment: do you have `smbclient` installed? can you remove it and use `system-config-printer` to install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went on `Printers/Add/Network Printer/Kyocera P3055dn ($IP)` selected `ÀppSocket/HP JetDirect` [image]. Then `Provide PPD file` selected the file I've downloaded before from https://www.kyoceradocumentsolutions.eu/en/support/downloads.name-L2V1L2VuL3ByaW50ZXJzL0VDT1NZU1AzMDUwRE4=.html%60 [image]
then followed the instruction.

I now have a separate printer that prints successfully. The issue was therefore that the drivers where there but not automatically used.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have a modern, AirPrint-capable device that is suitable for driverless printing. You give its URI as (using the printer you mention in the question as an example):

`Kyocera ECOSYS P3055dn` → `ipps://Kyocera%20ECOSYS%20P3055dn._ipps._tcp.local/`

Now set up a print queue with `lpadmin -p "PRINTER" -v "URI" -E -m everywhere`. Substitute for `URI`, and `PRINTER` of course. For the printer given in the example above, run:

```bash
sudo lpadmin -p P3050 -v "ipps://Kyocera%20ECOSYS%20P3055dn._ipps._tcp.local/" -E -m everywhere
```

and test printing with:

```bash
lp -d P3050 /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

Comment: This might be an answer, too. But I solved the problem already using AirPrint so I created an answer myself describing how I did it. If you are interested, I can try your method, too.

Comment: This successfully created a new printer for me with a plausible URI but when I send a print job after a few seconds CUPS still says *Print job was not accepted.*